# Row wise cross product Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to do cross product between every row of one `Eigen::MatrixXd dir` with corresponding row of `Eigen::MatrixXd v0v2` and save the result in another `Eigen::MatrixXd pvec`.

Initialization of pvec : `Eigen::MatrixXd pvec(v0v2.rows(), 3);`

I have tried this dirty method:

`for(size_t i = 0; i < v0v2.rows(); i++){
     pvec.row(i) = dir.row(i).cross(v0v2.row(i));
}`

I get this error : `THIS_METHOD_IS_ONLY_FOR_VECTORS_OF_A_SPECIFIC_SIZE`

I thought this would be because of column-major/row-major issue so I added `.transpose()` but that doesn't help either.
I could always do a dirtier personal cross product element wise something like this:

`Vec3 crossProduct(const Vec3<T> &v) const
    { return Vec3<T>(y * v.z - z * v.y, z * v.x - x * v.z, x * v.y - y * v.x); }`
but I would like to do an Eigen method.
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments of `.cross` must be known at compile-time to be of size 3.
Try declaring your matrices as `Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 3> dir(N, 3);`, etc.

Comment: You can also use the abbreviation `Eigen::MatrixX3d dir(N, 3);`.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Do I still need to do this in a loop? Additionally, I am declaring the matrices out of the function and calling the function with the matrices by reference. It still gives me the same error.

Comment: @RickM. did you ever figure it out? What did you end up doing? A `for` loop? xkcd relevant as always, https://xkcd.com/979/